# Spark executor self-exiting due to driver disassociated in Kubernetes with client deploy-mode

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have Spark driver running in a Kubernetes pod with client deploy-mode and it tries to start an executor.
Executor will fail with error:

```
{"type":"log", "level":"ERROR", "name":"STREAMING_OTHERS", "time":"2022-01-14T12:29:38.318Z", "timezone":"UTC", "class":"dispatcher-Executor", "method":"spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.logError(73)", "log":"Executor self-exiting due to : Driver 192-168-39-71.mni-system.pod.cluster.local:40752 disassociated! Shutting down.\n"}
```

Then driver will attempt to start another executor which fails with same error and this goes on and on.

In the driver pod, I see only following errors:

```
22/01/14 12:26:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on 192.168.43.250:
22/01/14 12:27:16 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on 192.168.43.233:
22/01/14 12:27:59 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 3 on 192.168.43.221:
22/01/14 12:28:43 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 4 on 192.168.43.217:
22/01/14 12:29:27 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 5 on 192.168.43.197:
22/01/14 12:30:10 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 6 on 192.168.43.237:
22/01/14 12:30:53 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 7 on 192.168.43.196:
22/01/14 12:31:42 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 8 on 192.168.43.228:
22/01/14 12:32:31 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 9 on 192.168.43.254:
22/01/14 12:33:14 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 10 on 192.168.43.204:
22/01/14 12:33:57 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 11 on 192.168.43.231:
```

What is wrong? And how can I get executors running correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cluster is disconnected. Which platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Kubernetes running on private cloud running OpenStack

Comment: Hi! Please note that the answers section is for answers only. If you have additional information to add to your question, please edit it and add the new details. For now, please delete this post if it's not a valid answer for the question.